# loading file with char pointer

Tags: c++, file, pointers, load, char

I have a class that loads data from a file that requires `char* fileName`, but don't have a clear understanding on how to use it in this manner.

```
// Constructor
Foo(char* fileName)
```

I understand that a `char` only takes in a single character, but may someone clarify on how to use this?

Comment: Pointers can point to more than one of something.  It expects a null terminated array of characters (representing a string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char*` is a "pointer to `char`". That is, it holds the address of a `char` object. It is very common to use pointers that point to the first element in an array. That is, if you increase the address by 1, you'll get the address of the next element in the array.

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│     │     │     │     │     │     │     │     │     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
   ^
   └─ pointer to first element of an array
```

C-style strings are usually stored in arrays of `char`. For example, here we are storing the string `"filename.txt"` in an array of `char`:

```
char str[] = "filename.txt";
```

The name of an array can be implicitly converted to a pointer that points at its first element. That is, `str` can be used as though it were a pointer to the `f` character. That pointer is of type `char*`.

This is why we often consider `char*` variables to be a C-style string. Although it is really just a pointer, they're usually assumed to be pointing at the first `char` in an array. The array is also most often assumed to be null-terminated, which means that there is a `char` with value `0` marking the end of the string. The string looks something like this in memory:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ f │ i │ l │ e │ n │ a │ m │ e │ . │ t │ x │ t │\0 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

You could therefore, because of the array-to-pointer conversion, pass the array `str` to your constructor like so:

```
Foo foo(str);
```

Note, however, that passing a string literal to your constructor directly is deprecated in C++03 and completely invalid in C++11. You can't do this:

```
Foo foo("filename.txt");
```

The problem with this is that this string literal is of type "array of 13 `const` `char`". After conversion to pointer, it's a `const char*`. You can't pass a `const char*` to a `char*` parameter because it would violate `const`-correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Historically creators of C have considered we could pass pointers where we could pass arrays, and vice versa.

If you think a little at the concept they are closely related. A pointer can browse many parts of memory( including an array which is bytes of memory that are one besides the other).

Using a pointer rather than an array, and using the ++ and -- operator (what we call pointer arithmetics) you can move inside memory, just like you move in your array with the index value.

The norm in C strings is to have the final '\0' character delimiting the end of a string. Move your pointer until this end, and you then have your whole string array.

Answer (score 0):

A `char*` is a pointer to a character. 
A filename can be an array of characters `char fileName[12] = "myFile.txt";`[Apart from `string` etc ] In this case, a `char*` pointer is used to point to the 1st character of this array. When you have to print this, the compiler picks up the address given by the pointer [k.a. base address] and keeps printing each character by obtaining its address. The address of a `char` is obtained by adding the subscript to the base address until `\n`

So you can make use of

```
char* fileName = "myFile.txt"; or char fileName[11] = "myFile.txt";
Foo(fileName);
```

or Foo("myFile.txt");